# Populate RDS on creation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

Currently creating an RDS per account for several different AWS accounts. I use Cloudformation scripts for this.
When creating these databases I would like for them to have a similar structure. I created an SQL which I can successfully run manually after the script has run. I would like to however execute this automatically as part of running the script.

My solution so far is to create a EC2 instance with a dependency on the RDS to run once and then manually delete it later but this is not a suitable solution. I couldn't find any other way though?

Is it possible to run a query as part of a cloudformation script? 
FYI: I'm creating a 11.5 Postgres instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to use [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

But this requires some new development. But if you have already EC2 instance that does populate the rds from its UserData you can **automate its termination** as follows:

1. Set [InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-instanceinitiatedshutdownbehavior) to `termiante`
2. At the end of UserData execute `shutdown -h now` to shutdown the instance.

Since your shutdown behavior is `terminate`, the instance will be **automatically terminated**.

Comment: Thnx again Marcin. I will check out the custom resources. I don't mind a little bit of dev work, so long as I can automate most of it.

Comment: Is there another way using FARGATE? Your solution provided could work but in my situation is a bit cumbersome. I already have got FARGATE tasks up-and running using scheduled actions as per your last answer. Really looking for a way to run it just once.

Comment: @Ludo21South What do you mean fargate? In your question there is no mention of using fargate?

Comment: I mean instead of using an EC2 instance it would be easier for me to run a FARGATE task. I already have the provisioning inside a docker image parameterised. I believe to be pretty close to this solution.

Comment: @Ludo21South Yes, if its easier then ec2 instance, then why not.

Comment: I think I need to check this into another question. My question was really "how can I run my fargate task once at the start of the cloudformation script". I do think we're getting offtopic here though.

Comment: @Ludo21South Yes, I'm confused. Your question did not mention fargate or ecs, so I answered based on what your wrote, i.e. how to run ec2 instance once, without manually deleting it.

Comment: Yes, therefor I will ask a new question and close this accepting the answer. I should've been more clear in the options.

Comment: @Ludo21South Thanks, and I think its good idea to make new question with all the new details.